# Two equal shaped dataframes: How to get a dataframe with the minimun for each cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

From two equal shaped dataframes like the following:

```
1       11      22
2       330     440
3       55      66
4       770     880
5       99      0


1       110     220
2       33      44
3       550     660
4       77      88
5       990     0
```

I need a dataframe like the following

```
1       11      22
2       33      44
3       55      66
4       77      88
5       99      0
```

That is: the minimun for each of the cells

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`np.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html)

```
np.minimum(df1, df2)
```

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    11    22
1     2    33    44
2     3    55    66
3     4    77    88
4     5    99     0
```

Answer (score 3):

Let do with `pandas`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).min(level=0)
Out[189]: 
    1   2
1  11  22
2  33  44
3  55  66
4  77  88
5  99   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably:

```
np.where(df1 < df2, df1, df2)
```

Or if you want a DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1 < df2, df1, df2),
             index=df1.index,
             columns=df1.columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
df1.where(df1<df2,df2)
```

We can also use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

```
df1.mask(df1>df2,df2)
```

---

**Other method** [`DataFrame.combine`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html):

```
df1.combine(df2, np.minimum)
```

**Output**

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    11    22
1     2    33    44
2     3    55    66
3     4    77    88
4     5    99     0
```